# Redirecting from domain to www.domain

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I'm having a problem with Joomla and the redirect from non www to www urls. Maybe it's not a Joomla problem at all. I've changed my .htaccess to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

which is working find, except that it cuts the rest of the url. If I'm typing mydomain.com/somesite I get redirect to www.mydomain.com

Any hints?

**EDIT:** Found out that it is a language plugin problem. I've got two languages installed. On the primary it works fine, the second language always redirects to the index.

**SOLUTION:** Thanks for all the help. Finally i figured it out. It wasn't the Condition or Rule, but the position in my .htaccess. Joomla has a "Custom redirects" Section. But if you place the code there, it won't work. If you place it directly after the RewriteEngine On it'll do it's job!

Comment: I'm not sure about this; But as far as I know Google sees www. as a subdomain(And therefore something different than domain.com). You may want to switch it around and redirect people who use www. to the non-www version for SEO purposes.

Comment: The problem still exists. My subfolders get cut off.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use below on my website, and worked fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thats even worse. Now it adds index.php at the end, but removes my subfolders.

Comment: @Andi i wanted to redirect all www to non www. But I have edited my answer to suit ur need. It will redirect any req to www URL now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```